# How to get gridview column value in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to get the AppId from  gridView in codebehind, if I clicked the edit image button in second row.

[image: Application List]

**Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="AppId" DataField="AppID" />


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ControlStyle-Width="20px" ItemStyle-Width="130px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMailCamp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/Mail.png"
                            Height="18px" ToolTip="Send Mail Campaign" CssClass="grdImageAlign"  CommandName="SendMail" OnClick="btnMailCamp_Click"    />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgViewApp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/application-view-list-icon.png"
                            Height="18px" ToolTip="View Appplication" CssClass="grdImageAlign" CommandName="View" OnClick="btnView_Click" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditApp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/Action-edit-icon.png"
                            Height="18px" ToolTip="Edit Application" CssClass="grdImageAlign" CommandName="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDeleteApp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/Trash-can-icon.png"
                            Height="18px" ToolTip="Delete Application" CssClass="grdImageAlign" CommandName="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // I need to get the current row appId, I use this appId in next page for sql query
  Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID="+AppID);
}
```

Comment: you can use data key or hidden field approach , just look here http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/01/08/get-primary-key-on-row-command-gridview.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this....Don't Define Click Event of Button....Define Button Like this...

```
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditApp" runat="server"
 ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/Action-edit-icon.png" 
    Height="18px" ToolTip="Edit Application" CssClass="grdImageAlign" 
CommandName="Edit"/>
```

And 
Define Your GridView RowEditing event  Like this....

```
 protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
          Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID="+YourGridViewId.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text);
        }
```

**Edit:**
I think you have problem in definig RowEditingEvent.....ok you can do this...nothing to change just write this code in you Click event...

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ImageButton ib = sender as ImageButton;
        GridViewRow row = ib.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
  Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID="+YourGridViewId.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditApp" runat="server"
 ImageUrl="~/Images/AppSetup/Action-edit-icon.png" 
    Height="18px" ToolTip="Edit Application" CssClass="grdImageAlign" 
CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AppID") %>'/>

    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string appid= (sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument;
      Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID="+appid
    }
```

Comment: Iam getting this error If i use the above code,  Error'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NewEditIndex' and no extension method 'NewEditIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If I changed the EventArgs to GridViewEditEventArgs  Iam getting error like    "CS0123: No overload for 'btnEdit_Click' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler'"

Comment: you can not do that...you to remove onlcik event of your image button...define rowediting event of gridview show you grid view apsx code ..i the line  mean where you define gridview id and other property

Comment: @Vignesh see my answer now carefully relace your buttonm code like i define here...and define row editing.....Event of gridview and wrrite code like write above/....code there...

Comment: Another thing is if the AppId column is moved to 2nd position in table so in such case the aboved code will get the wrong column value right? for that is there any way to use column name instead of mentioning the index as numbers

Comment: @Vignesh see another edit...define command argument of button like i define and write code like that...

Answer (score 2):

You can get grid view cell value from this.

```
GridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[CellIndex].Text
```

Here "RowIndex" is row number from which you want to get data and "CellIndex" is cell number from which you want to get data.

I think event "OnRowCommand" of gridview is best suited for your problem.
use blow link for more details

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click

Comment: This is the best and fastest way ! +1

Answer (score 1):

it should be with [commandargument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx) 
aspx

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditApp" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AppID") %>' runat="server" ... OnClick="btnEdit_Click"/>
```

code

```
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
          int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID="+categoryId);
        }
```

or u can use [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.postbackurl.aspx) property of imagebutton and it would be like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEditApp" PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID={0}", Eval("AppID")) %>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippet.

This is the code in aspx file having two columns DataBound "AppId" and TemplateColumn "Action" containing Image Button. Observe CommandName and CommandArgument properties of Image Button. Also Define OnRowCommand Event listener for gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            EnableViewState="false" onrowcommand="grdDisplayData_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AppId" DataField="AppId" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="MyEdit" 
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ImageAction">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Width="15px" Height="15px" 
                            CommandName="ImgEdit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code behind code. The e.CommandArument returns the index of the row in which the image button was clicked.

```
protected void grdDisplayData_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "ImgEdit")
            {
                int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                Response.Redirect("/Secured/EditApplication.aspx?AppID=" + grdDisplayData.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.Trim());
            }
        }
```

Let me know if this fixed your problem.

Cheers!!!
Piyush Deshpande

Comment: Whats the error you're getting? If you would be having more rows in the grid than what is supported by Int16, change "Convert.ToInt16" to either "Convert.ToInt32" or "Convert.ToInt64" and check if the error goes away, if not post the error. Cheers!